# What's the difference between these variations?

Tags: difference

1. He objected to me marrying his daughter.
2. He objected to my marrying his daughter.
3. He objected to my marrying of his daughter.

Comment: (2) is correct, (1) might be used in casual speech, (3) is wrong (you don't 'marry of' someone).

Comment: I would disagree slightly with @KateBunting here as although I would use (2) I find (1) is very frequent which makes me feel I am rather old fashioned in preferring (2)